# VLOOKUP or INDEX-MATCH for text from bottom to the top with reference to another sheet in the workbook

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

I am making a log for work and in one of the columns, I need a formula that fills each cell with the latest text information from another sheet in the same workbook. I have attached a picture of the worksheet I am working in and a picture of the referenced worksheet.

**The worksheet I need the formula in**
[image: the worksheet I need the formula in]

**The worksheet with the reference cells**
[image: the worksheet with the reference cells]

In image 1, there are 2 column titles highlighted. Column 'A' and Column 'S'. Column A is the id of one of my animals, and column S is supposed to have a date/initial in there for my macro to work. However, people forget to fill it in and only fill it in the sheet from image 2 in Column 'P'. Because we reuse the same animal more than once the information that goes into column S in the first image always needs to be the newest information from the reference sheet. I know how to do a VLOOKUP with the dates, I have already done those, but because I need the cell to populate with text instead of numerical values, I am having trouble.

I will list some formulas I have tried that are supposed to go from the bottom to the top but don't work and maybe just need to tweak and some that work if I was going from the top to the bottom.

Formulas that don't work going from the bottom to the top but I'd think would:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(FIND(A18,BREEDING!D:D)),P:P)
=INDEX(BREEDING!P:P,MATCH(A21,BREEDING!D:D,0))
=LOOKUP(2,1/(BREEDING!D:D=A21),BREEDING:P:P)
```

Formulas that do work but go from the top to the bottom:

```
=(VLOOKUP(A17,BREEDING!D:Q,13,FALSE))
```

References:
Column A: Animal ID that is present in the 1st image
Column D: Animal ID that is present in the 2nd image
Column S: 'Date Weaned' cell that will contain the formula and information from the 2nd image should populate into
Column P: The actual date weaned that should go into column S of the 1st image

TL;DR
In image 1, cells in column S should have the latest **text** information from column P of image 2 if the information from Column A of image 1 matches the information from Column D of image 2

Answer (score 0):

Formula that you could use is below

```
=INDEX(BREEDING!P:P;AGGREGATE(14;6;ROW(BREEDING!D:D)/(BREEDING!D:D=A2);1))
```

how it works - the index is simple, the aggregate the is main thing - it uses 14 as first parameter which is function LARGE (return k-th largest value) and then the 6 is the most important, because that means "skip errors". This is vital, because when you divide by (BREEDING!D:D=A2) it divides by 0 or 1 based on false/true so creates lot of errors and keeps only the lines with Animal ID equal to Animal ID of the line. Then it uses LARGE function on all lines with that Animal ID and because of the last part ";1))" it returns the highest row number where the Animal ID matches. This way you should be able to get the value from your second sheet for the newest (highest row number) line.

The formula can be quite resource-intensive so you might have to repaste as values - if you are periodically running a macro on the data you can have it also apply the formula and then change to values if it gets too long to calculate every time you want to change something...